# how could edit value of radio buttons in php

Tags: php, html

In php form I get the data from radio button to database. It works well. But in edit page how do I get the checked value from the database?

my code is:

```
             <div class="data">
                <div class="label1">PCDC:</div>
                <div style="text-align:right;width:49px;float:left;">
                <input type="radio" name="pcdc"  value="yes" style="vertical-align: middle; margin: 0px;">YES
                </div>
                <div style="text-align:right;width:46px;float:left;">

                <input type="radio" name="pcdc"  value="no" style="vertical-align: middle; margin: 0px;">NO
                   </div>
         </div>
```

Comment: Where is your php code?

Comment: Generic question, generic answer - you should add 'checked' attribute on edit page - based on db value you got?

Comment: post your edit page code

Answer (score 0):

Please try the code like that way ::
Suppose your variable name of radio button values is "$val" then use this $val variable like that way.

```
<input type="radio" name="pcdc" <?php if($val == 'yes') { echo "checked='checked'"; } ?>  value="yes" style="vertical-align: middle; margin: 0px;">YES
<input type="radio" name="pcdc"  <?php if($val == 'no') { echo "checked='checked'"; } ?> value="no" style="vertical-align: middle; margin: 0px;">NO
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try following code to

```
$('input[name="pcdc"][value="yes"]').prop('checked',true);
```

Above is a jQuery solution, advantage is when you have number of radio button, no need to check for each element.